# Type Mismatch error stepping through an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following code. I'm passing in a cell's value from column "d" as a string (a list of days of the week, could be one day or as many as all 7 days) into this function. I'm also using the fuction to fill an array of Integers. I'm getting a type mismatch at the indicated line and I can't figure out why. Especially since I Dim the array right before filling it and stepping through it. I'd appreciate any help/explaination. Option Explicit is turned on.

```
Public i as Integer

Public Function ParseColumnD(cellvalue as String) as String

Dim BREdaysString() as String
Dim daysAsInt() As Integer

BREdaysString() = Split(cellvalue, ", ")

For Each i in BREdaysString()
    If BREdaysString(i) = "Monday" Then           '<-----Type Mismatch error here.
        daysAsInt(i) = 4
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Tuesday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 5
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Wednesday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 6
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Thursday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 7
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Friday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 8
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Saturday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 9
    ElseIf BREdaysString(i) = "Sunday" Then
        daysAsInt(i) = 10
    End If
Next

'to check to make sure the conversion from days of the week to integers is correct 
'I take the int array and put it as the function's string, return it and put in another cell.

For Each i in daysAsInt()
   If i = 1 Then
      ParseColumnD = daysAsInt(i)
   ElseIf i > 1 Then
      ParseColumnD = ParseColumnD & ", " & daysAsInt(i)
   End If
Next
End Funciton
```

In the regular module I use the function like this...

```
Sub MySub()

Dim BREitems as Range
Dim lastrow as Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Set BREitems = Range("a5:a" & lastrow)

For Each i in BREitems
    Cells(i.Row, "g").value = ParseColumnD(Cells(i.row, "d"))
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `For...Next` loop here to iterate over the array, using [`LBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/lbound-function) and [`Ubound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function), not a `For Each` loop.

```
For i = LBound(BREdaysString) to Ubound(BREdaysString)
```

A `For Each` loop would work if you did the following:

```
For Each i in BREdaysString()
     If i = "Monday" Then
```

Obviously using a better variable name then `i`, and `Dim`ming as a `String`, as this is pretty confusing. But you can't use `i` as an *index* if  you're using  a `For Each` loop. That would be like trying to do `If BREdaysString("Monday") = "Monday" Then`

I don't see the point of `i` being `Public` here either. And [just use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) .

Comment: changing this loop worked great! thank you.

i is a public variable because I use it all in loops all over this project. I don't want to have to declare it in every sub/function. I only included that here because I said option explicit is on and I wanted to make sure the example code declared all variables.

Comment: Having it `Public` is bad practice, IMO.